# How do I setup a project to use WcfSvcHost.exe and WcfTestClient.exe

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to write my first WCF project.  I have created a project of type WCF library.

In the video I am working from, when F5 is pressed (start debugger) the WCF test client starts up.

What do I have to do to my project settings to get the WcfTestClient to start up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project and choose "Propterties"

Select the "Debug Tab"

Set the "Start Action" to "Start project"

Set the "command line arguments:" to /client:"WcfTestClient.exe"